# How can i create a UIView class that include labels and textfields in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

[image]

I have many objects like this. I want to reuse them for example send values to view class. Phone label and textfield id etc.

Drag and drop a UIView and set the constraints. Go to identity inspector and select class that you created.

How can i do this efficient way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`@IBDesignable` and `@IBInspectable`](https://medium.com/better-programming/what-are-ibdesignable-and-ibinspectable-in-swift-1e3440797d9) if you want to configure your custom views and have them rendered in IB.

In this way your own custom views are getting very close to iOS UI views.

In your view controller you can then create outlets for your `UIView` subclasses: `@IBOutlet weak var myCustomView: MyCustomView?`.

Because you've now created your own composite view containing a number of UIKit objects, you won't/can't create outlets for these UIKit subviews.

You must now decide what API you want to shape for your composite view. You could make the UIKit subviews accessible or you could hide them with your own, more abstract functions.

I've linked one tutorial, but other good ones are easy to find.

Comment: For example i added a few uiviews like this. How can i manage object id's ? I need to connect every textfields and labels to viewController ?